# How to open Spark UI when working on a server?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark on my server with Ubuntu. I use the shell only and there is no UI for the server other than that. There is always an option of looking at the stats of Spark like jobs, cpus, memory etc when working on local computer on a web browser.

Is there a way that I can view all that information locally on the server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`spark-shell` always starts a web UI on port 4040 by default. If the server has no graphical interface, you can either use a text-based browser, such as [Links](http://links.twibright.com/), or access port 4040 from another machine, such as your laptop. You may need to run `ufw allow 4040` to unblock the port in the firewall.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your spark master web ui is running on remote.example.com on port 8082, you can use SSH tunneling to open the web ui on your local machine -

On your local terminal type -

```
ssh -L 8082:remote.example.com:8082 yourusername@remote.example.com
```

Now, in your local web browser open
http://localhost:8082

You should see the web ui.

Answer (score 2):

I think a python should be running on the server, so you can use this command:

```
python -m webbrowser -n http://host:port
```

(for example the application detail ui: http://localhost:4040).
It gives a shell based browser if the server has no graphical interface

Comment: Its not showing anything, and normal user prompt comes again.

Answer (score 1):

In local mode, you can only view the web UI during the duration of the job. You can also start a history server which stores all the information which you need. I would say try running on standalone mode. Follow the below link to run Spark on standalone mode.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

Basically you need to start three services,

start-master.sh

start-slave.sh

stop-history-server.sh

This will start the history server on 18080 port.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH tunnelling to achieve this, for example if the Spark Web UI on your remote server is exposed on port 4040 you can run the command `ssh -N -L 7000:127.0.0.1:4040 remote.server.username@remote.server.ip` on your local machine terminal in order to access the Spark Web UI using `http://127.0.0.1:7000/` on your browser.